# css not affecting the page when using with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie to bootstrap. I have developed a weppage using bootstrap3. I'm using these two classes on the same element, but the css is not having any effect:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 auminascroll">
    dfgdgdfgdfgsdfgh cxzvdzfhfdbfd fbfddf
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 auminascroll">fghfdghfdhdfhfdsh</div>
<div class="col-md-4 auminascroll">dfgdsgdsfg</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.col-md-4 .auminascroll {

   height: 50px;
   overflow-y: auto; 

}
```

I am not getting a scroll when using above code. If I put `height: 50px; overflow-y: auto;` in a style tag, my code works fine. Why is this css not having an effect when using it with this bootstrap class? Is there any problem with my code?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: is bootstrap loaded in you webpage? css and js files?

Comment: seeing your html and CSS, the only plausible explanation would be that this CSS file is not loaded (up to you to check if it is) OR that this rule is overruled with a more specific one coming from somewhere else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're nearly there! When using a selector to choose two classes there should be no space between the class names - they just need separating with a dot.

```
.col-md-4.auminascroll { /* no space between the two classes */

 height: 50px;
 overflow-y: auto; 

}
```

Your code (where there's a space between the two classes: `.class-a .class-b` would actually look for an element of `class-b` *inside* and element of `class-a`.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="auminascroll">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help, it can be confusing that multiple classes are separated with a space in HTML, yet a space denotes a descendant class in CSS. (if you'd like any more clarifications please let me know, and if you're happy please accept my answer)

Comment: i try to accept,but the alert shows you cannot accept answer in some minutes.i will accept the answer after time expires

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong css selector. You need to use it like:

```
.col-md-4.auminascroll {

  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto; 

}
```